# VB.Net parameterless method seems to be accepting parameters

Tags: vb.net

I have the following function definition:

```
Function Parameterless() as String
```

There are no overrides or overloads of it. The following line will happily compile and run:

```
Dim s as String = Parameterless(1)
```

What is going on?

Comment: The wonders of Vb... :-)

Comment: Are you sure that you are not overloading/shadowing/overriding the function in a Partial Class? My Visual Studio tells me "Too many parameters".

Comment: switch to a more reliable and stricter c#

Comment: @Kokombads: what strange suggestions here. Guys, focus on this issue instead of suggesting using english instead of french. Or don't comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What happens here is indeed strange and a VB.NET oddity.

Both, methods and indexers, are called with `()` (as opposed to C# where you use `[]` for the latter). Because of downwards compatibility these parentheses aren't mandatory. You can call any method that doesn't take any parameters without. So you can use:

```
Dim s As String = Parameterless
```

and you can use (recommended for this reason)

```
Dim s As String = Parameterless()
```

But why you can use `Parameterless(0)` even if there is no overload? Because the method returns a `String` which has an indexer. So if you want the first character of the returned string you could either use (recommended):

```
Dim firstLetter As Char = Parameterless()(0)
```

or (not recommended but your case)

```
Dim firstLetter As Char = Parameterless(0)
```

This works because there is no overload and the VB.NET compiler decides that you want to call the method without parameters and then you want to use the indexer on the string.

If the method would not return a string (or any other type that has an indexer) but for example an integer you would get a compiler error.

---

- In VB.NET they have called it [Default properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property)
- In C# they are called [Indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/)

Answer (score 1):

I tried replicating it based on your code

```
 Private Function Parameterless() As String
        Return "abcd"
    End Function
```

I added a button

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim per As String = Parameterless(1)

        TextBox1.Text = per
    End Sub
```

the output displayed on the textbox:
b

so the number param there will determine the index number of characters to be displayed

Answer (score 1):

"Default" Do this trick

```
Public Class User
    Default ReadOnly Property Number(i As Integer) As String
        Get
            If i = 1 Then Return "Mark"
            Return "Bob"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
Private Function TestFunction () As User
    Return New User
End Function
```

So  output will be

```
    TestFunction(1) 'Mark
    TestFunction(2) 'Bob
```